# Programmatically (Java) retrieving the last Git tag for placing version info in software

Tags: java, git, tags

I've begun versioning my commits with git tag -a v2.3.4 -m 'some message'
so that I can label my software releases with version numbers (e.g. 2.3.4)

I'd like to have an "about" menu item in the software where a user could display what version they are running.

Is there a way to do this (preferably in Java) so that my app can "know" its version tag in git???

Comment: Do you mean to have this in your build script or in your live application?  The former would be much easier - just make it a build parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have your repo local:

```
import java.io.*;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String []args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
        String command = "git describe --abbrev=0 --tags";
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line; 
        String text = command + "\n";
        System.out.println(text);
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null)
        {
            text += line;
            System.out.println("Line: " + line);
        }
    }
}
```

Maybe check with https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compile_java8_online.php

---

If you have your repo on Github:

`https://api.github.com/repos/YOURNAME/YOURREPO/tags`

For example:

https://api.github.com/repos/git/git/tags

This will get you the newest 30 Git repo tags.

Comment: Thanks.  As long as the Runtime.exec with the git command works the same cross platform this does it.

Comment: Just realized my production environment isn't under git management so the command won't work anywhere but my development environment.   I wonder if I can do an empty clone in my production environment so the command will run there.

Comment: Do you use GitHub?

Comment: Yes.  That's where the repo is.

Comment: Yeah.  That should do it.   I start to wonder whether pulling the last version tag at runtime is the correct way to do this.   Do you think it should be "baked in" to the software at build-time rather than fetching from github?